# Get Dataframe Name fromlist of Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I've created a list of data frames that I'd like to iterate over.  The goal is to loop over them and write CSVs,  but that's not relevant to the question.

I can loop over the list just fine by enumerating, but I'd like to be able to access the **name** of the data frame that was added to the list, to name the CSV file.  Is it possible to access the names of the individual data frames?

Alternatively, is there a better approach to iterating over multiple data frames in this manner?

Comment: Can you add some sample data as well along with the question?

Comment: I don't know what data/code would be useful to help with this question.  I have a list of dataframes (list_df) created using .append().

Comment: You should create a dict rather than a list, and use the df name as dict key. Then you can access the dataframes by name.